# How can I run zsh within a zsh login session and not lose my aliases?

Tags: shell

I think I'm missing some core shell concept. My current shell is set to `/bin/zsh`, when I open a new terminal session, I can use my aliases:

```
> echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
> ll
total 320
drwxr-xr-x@   7 nacho  staff   238B Aug 24 14:16 ..
-rw-rw----    1 nacho  staff    26K Aug 24 14:47 something
```

If I run the zsh command, I lose my aliases:

```
> zsh
> ll
zsh: command not found: ll
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It works in `zsh`, but not in `zsh`?

Comment: It works in login shells but not in non-login shells

Answer (score 1):

Where did you define your aliases? Note that an alias is not exported. Hence you need to define it at a place which is automatically read every time a new shell is opened.

Read the Zsh man-page to see, which files are sourced in which cases. For instance, if you need the aliases only in interactive shells, you put them into `~/.zshrc`.